# Mysql how to find a table is fragmented

Tags: mysql, database-administration

Currently I am stuck in a situation to find Fragmented Tables, Through query

I am using `SHOW TABLE STATUS`

Its giving me Details like

> Table_Name, schema_Name, Data_Length, Index_Length, Data_Free Etc.

By using this information how to Signify that this table is `FRAGMENTED`

I need to write a query which is give fragmented tables name.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I google it but i did not got any satisfied answer for this.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the query

```
select  
   ENGINE, 
   TABLE_NAME,
   Round( DATA_LENGTH/1024/1024) as data_length , 
   round(INDEX_LENGTH/1024/1024) as index_length, 
   round(DATA_FREE/ 1024/1024) as data_free 
from information_schema.tables  
where  DATA_FREE > 0;
```

After, you should get fragmentation ratio: (data_free / (data_length + index_length) ) * 100

If this number pretty big, I would say more then 10%, then your table is fragmented. 
10% is discussion number. Some administrators uses 20%. Anyway, if you see big number, then you should pay attention on the table

Comment: As per you said (data_free / (data_length + index_length) ) * 100. this is giving me Output value this much (8295000.0000).

Comment: give me separate data_free, data_length and  index_length

Comment: Then is table is fragmented?

Comment: give numbers please. 8295000 looks like too big

Comment: Data_free = 1659, Data_length = 5, Data_length = 6 and (data_free / (data_length + index_length) ) * 100 = (15725.1185)

Comment: Data_free = 1659, Data_length = 0, Data_length = 0 and (data_free / (data_length + index_length) ) * 100 = (8295000.0000). see this table is having only 10 records. But this values (15725.1185) table hold 73177 records.

Comment: i found this explanation, suppose it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300893/why-is-mysqls-data-free-larger-than-data-and-indexes-combined

Comment: While I google it i found that page but that is not satisfy. That why i arise question in stack. Anyhow thanks a lot my friend...